# Build Errors after downloading most recent Angular 2 quickstart files

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 2 project that was working just fine on version 2.3, but I wanted to upgrade to version 2.4, so I downloaded the most recent quickstart files here: https://github.com/angular/quickstart

Then I replaced my tsconfig.json, package.json, and systemjs.config.js files with the ones from that quickstart project. Now I'm suddenly getting numerous isntances of the following errors:

> Build: Cannot find name 'Set'
>
> Build: Cannot find name 'Promise'
>
> Build: Cannot find name 'Map'

Why would  the tsconfig.json, package.json, and/or systemjs.config.js files from the most recent Quickstart project cause those errors?

I recently upgraded my TypeScript to 2.1.4 and thought that might be a problem, so I uninstalled it and went back to 2.0.3. Could that possibly be an issue somehow?

I'm sure someone will have a suggestion to change code in one or two of those files, but I shouldn't need to, should I? Shouldn't those just work out of the box?

Here are the files...

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

systemjs.config.js:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

EDIT: I changed those files back to what they were before, which got rid of the errors, then I created a new project with the Quickstart files I downloaded, and those errors showed up again. This proves it is not an error with my code. Are there issues with the 2.4 release? Are other people able to get their projects with version 2.4 to run?

UPDATE: I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

Comment: Did you do a clean npm install?

Comment: Yes, I deleted my node_modules folder, ran npm cache clean, then npm install

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10. Have never had issues until upgrading to 2.4.

Comment: I am unable to replicate it, I tried Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio Code, WebStorm, Sublime, and atom. The quick start project works fine. So the issues something to do with your Visual Studio 2015? I have TypeScript v2.1.4 installed btw.

Comment: Are you on Windows 10?

Comment: Yes I am on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Please try installing the typings module using the below and see if it helps:

```
      npm install -g typings
      typings install
```

Comment: Shouldn't need to do that, since he isn't using the old way to install typing definition for typescript <= 1.9. His package.json states he is using typescript 2.0+ which is using the new way to install the definition via @types.

Comment: This didn't work. For what it's worth, I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10. Have never had issues until upgrading to 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a dumb mistake. I have a couple of different Angular Apps inside my project and I forgot to change the tsconfig.json file in one of them. Once I updated the other one the build errors were resolved. This should probably just be deleted...